# How can I add id-s for variables with a specific conditions?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

In SAS I'd like to add id values to the variables with a specific conditions. I have the following code:

```
DATA market_new;
SET sashelp.cars;
if Make = 'Audi' then id = 0;
else id = _N_;  
RUN;

proc print data=market_new;
run;
```

Output:

[image]

The problem is that the id continues with 27, 28 etc. after the make isn't equal to Audi. My goal is to have 8, 9 instead.

Comment: Why does it matter if there is a gap in the ID values as long as they are unique?

Comment: it's for another task, not for this particularly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `SUM` (`+`) statement to track the *Audis*.

```
if make='Audi' then do;
  audi_seq + 1;        drop audi_seq;
  audi_id = audi_seq;
end;
else
  audi_id = 0;
```

Comment: It works fine! :) Can you explain it in more details? I'm a beginner in SAS.

Comment: The `SUM` statement syntax is *variable* `+` *expression* wherein the *variable* is implicitly `retain`ed.  `audi_seq` is only incremented upon the specific condition and the `id` receives the updated sequence value.  Also, because `audi_seq` is dropped from output, you may consider it a temporary variable.

Comment: Another question. How can I implement this code in macro? The else statement doesn't work for me.

Comment: Create a new question showing how you tried coding it as a macro and the errors or problems you saw in the log.  You probably don't need a macro.

Comment: Here is my question and the whole code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63996027/how-can-i-transform-this-code-into-macro?noredirect=1#comment113165662_63996027